# Unable to use Unbuntu GUI

Tags: gui

I am using ubuntu on workstation vmware. I installed today, it was using the gui, terminal very well. however, when I was doing it the second time, I see only command line..

I dont know what to do, I tried control+alt+f7, no use

[image]

Comment: try `apt install gdm`

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`apt install lightdm lightdm-settings`

Then try again:
`systemct enable --now lightdm`